# C# Track Process if it is killed

Tags: c#, .net, process

Is there an event or a way to capture the time when a process is killed externally from my application.

I have tried both these events below, but when I kill the proces in `TaskManager` it isnt reporting anything.

```
    private void startServer() 
    {
        proc = new Process();
        proc.Exited += proc_Exited;
        proc.Disposed += proc_Disposed;

    }

    void proc_Disposed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Report here
    }

    void proc_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        //Report here
    }
```

Comment: You could open a new instance of VS and attach the debugger to the working instance

Comment: OK, but are you saying that my code should be just working or am I missing something?

Comment: By definition a process can't know when it is killed. In order to report the way you are trying, the process has to execute code, and the code is killed... You're only non-debug option is to created another process to monitor the process you want to report on

Answer (score 2):

Exited and Disposed events will only fire if you close within your application (via your code on when user click on x button), and not from outside (kill from task manager).  There is no easy way to capture when somebody kills/terminate your application from task manager.  You could do api hooking to capture that.  Please take a look at [API hooking revealed](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2082/API-hooking-revealed) on how to do it.